# Saving Application State in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, network-programming, distributed

How can I save the application state for a node.js Application that consists mostly of HTTP request?

I have a script in Node.JS that works with a RESTful API to import a large number (10,000+) of products into an E-Commerce application. The API has a limit on the amount of requests that can be made and we are staring to brush up against that limit. On a previous run the script exited with a `Error: connect ETIMEDOUT` probably due to exceeding API limits. I would like to be able to try connecting 5 times and if that fails resume after an hour when the limit has been restored.

It would also be beneficial to save the progress throughout in case of a crash (power goes down, network crashes etc). And be able to resume the script from the point it left off.

I know that Node.js operates as a giant event-queue, all http requests and their callbacks get put into that queue (together with some other events). This makes it a prime target for saving the state of current execution. Other pleasant (not totally necessary for this project) would be being able to distribute the work among several machines on different networks to increase throughput.

So is there an existing way to do it? A framework perhaps? Or do I need to implement this myself, in that case, any useful resources on how this can be done would be appreciated.

Comment: What you want is a *persistent job queue*. There are many of them; one rather good looking one is [Kue](http://learnboost.github.com/kue/) (build on redis).

Comment: I think you are absolutely right. Kue is quite brilliant. So basically in the producer I would be reading my data file and in the consumer I could be adding/updating each product. So each product would be a separate job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say

> I know that Node.js operates as a giant event-queue, all http requests and their callbacks get put into that queue (together with some other events). This makes it a prime target for saving the state of current execution

Please feel free to comment or expound on this if you find it relevant to the answer.

That said, if you're simply looking for a persistence mechanism for this particular task, I might recommend [Redis](http://redis.io/), for a few reasons:

- It allows [atomic operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28database_systems%29) on many data types; for example, if you had an entry in Redis called `num_requests_made` that represented the number of requests made, you could increment this number easily in Redis using `INCR num_requests_made`, and it's guaranteed to be atomic, making it easier to scale to multiple workers.
- It has [several data types](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) that could prove useful for your needs; for example, a simple string could represent the number of API requests made during a certain period of time (as in the previous bullet point); you might store details on failed API request that need to be resubmitted in a list; etc.
- It provides [pub/sub mechanisms](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) which would allow you to communicate easily between multiple instances of the program.

If this sounds interesting or useful and you're not already familiar with Redis, I highly recommend trying out the [interactive tutorial](http://try.redis-db.com/), which introduces you to a few data types and commands for them. Another good piece of reading material is [A fifteen minute introduction to Redis data types](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro).

Comment: So Redis seems very similar to MongoDB with the exception that Mongo does not have Pub/Sub features. Distribution is not as big of a deal for me for this project as speed of development is. I have already worked with Mongo in Node.js (Mongoose). So I think it may be better to stick with it, unless you think otherwise?

Also I was talking about the even loop in Node.js when I mentioned the queue and how everything gets processed in order and internally represented as one or more queues.

Comment: Redis focuses more on atomicity and speed, but yeah, if you know Mongo you could definitely make it work for this application and use some other pub/sub tool if you ever wanted to (ZeroMQ, RabbitMQ, etc.), though I do think Redis is a better fit unless you're doing actual document storage (and Kue is backed by Redis anyway). As far as the event queue, I think I see what you're driving at, but I'm not sure how you'd reach in and save state without rolling something custom.

Comment: Yes thanks Brandon :). Both of you answers really helped me get a better sense of direction. I will open a follow up question. If you or @dan-d can add an answer that describes how to use Kue to do something similar I will mark it as the answer, thanks :).